# Efficient IDE tools for F#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, f#, ide, refactoring

I recently initiated my first F# project, using Visual Studio 2012. I was rather surprised (or, more precisely, disappointed) at the lack of IDE support for F#. For example, the classic Ctrl-r Ctrl-r shortcut for refactor rename appears to be completely absent. I installed the F# powertools extension, which does provide some support for this - but apparently only supports renaming in the F# part of the solution, and not e.g. C# parts of the solution (the solution contains both F# and C# projects).

Are there extensions to Visual Studio which provides cross-language refactor rename functionality?

In general, as a slightly loose question, what kind of IDE and/or IDE extensions do people find efficient for F# programming? I'm so used to the efficient VS2012 refactoring support for C# that I can't help to find its absence a considerable blow to efficient use of F#...

Comment: As far as I can tell - F# Power Tools is as good as it gets. Unfortunately, it's still nowhere near the level of C# + ReSharper, but it's *something*.

Comment: I feel that F# is in a frustrating catch-22 situation at the moment. Until F# gains more traction, there's no incentive to develop eg resharper for F#, but until there is a resharper for F#, the latter won't gain more traction.

Comment: Is refactoring really a significant portion of your time spent coding?  I would think that design/debugging would so important as to make refactoring mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidArno Yes, that is the sad reality right now.

Comment: @mydogisbox, refactoring (after making each new test pass) should be a very significant portion of your time spent coding. Debugging should be the non-event. I can't remember the last time I ran up the debugger; my unit tests do my testing/debugging for me.

Comment: @DavidArno Refactoring usually happens during the session in F# interactive and you are testing/changing a small part of the code, usually a single function. It's very rare when you need cross-project refactoring. Cross-language refactoring even more rare event.

Comment: @DavidArno Firstly red-green-refactor loop of TDD was developed for working against imperative OO languages (Java, C#, …). The use of FSI and the functional nature of F#, at the very least, should lead to consideration whether that is the right approach for development. Tools need to support the language and platform, not visa versa.

Comment: @Richard, that's an interesting assertion. I'm certainly not going to claim you are wrong (for you may know better than me), but it certainly feels wrong to me. Can you point me to anything I can read that argues that case?

Comment: @DavidArno: try [this post](http://codeofrob.com/entries/on-testing-and-the-repl-in-clojure.html) - it's about Clojure, but the same holds true for F# and FSI - or a dozen others you get when googling "repl vs tdd".